# AFNetworking JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am getting response for my web-service like this when I run it in browser: `IN.Tags.Share.handleCount({"count":5,"fCnt":"5","fCntPlusOne":"6","url":"http:\\myWebService?postid=24"});`

But when I use afnetworking code to get response it gives error like:

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

how can I get response like only :

```
({"count":5,"fCnt":"5","fCntPlusOne":"6","url":"http:\\myWebService?postid=24"})
```

Comment: plz try with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];`

Comment: I have tried  this..but it gives same error

Comment: also you have to check from PHP side code. Sometimes php code not acceptiing json. then PHO need to update some code

Comment: solved...I need to add &format=json in my webservise